# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split' to convert comma separated labels into a list

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, classification

Hi please help me with this code. It shows this error. I was trying out the code example from (https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/skin-cancer-detection-using-tensorflow-in-python) this website.

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-39f8cfd85d69> in <module>
 
 28 # you should replace "data" path to your extracted dataset path

 29 # don't replace if you used download_and_extract_dataset() function

---> 30 generate_csv("data/train", {"nevus": 0, "seborrheic_keratosis": 0, 
"melanoma": 1})

31 generate_csv("data/valid", {"nevus": 0, "seborrheic_keratosis": 0, 
"melanoma": 1})

 32 generate_csv("data/test", {"nevus": 0, "seborrheic_keratosis": 0, 
 "melanoma": 1})


<ipython-input-7-39f8cfd85d69> in generate_csv(folder, labels)
  6     label2int = {}
  7     if labels:
  ----> 8         labels = labels.split(",")
  9         for label in labels:
 10             string_label, integer_label = label.split("=")

 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VckXp.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your calls to `generate_csv`, change

```
{"nevus": 0, "seborrheic_keratosis": 0, "melanoma": 1}
```

to:

```
"nevus=0,seborrheic_keratosis=0,melanoma=1"
```

It wants a string, not a dict.  The string consists of a sequence of comma-separated bindings, where each binding is of the form "name=value".

Comment: Hi I tried your solution but it shows a different error.

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'split' 
----> 8         labels = labels.split(",")

Comment: @PriyaS Remove the curly braces.  Make the *exact* replacement I showed.  You only replaced the center portion.  Replace the "before" text with the "after" text, exactly and completely.  The "before" text includes the curly braces.  The "after" text does not.  You need to pass a string.  Since you didn't remove the curly braces, you were passing a `set` instead, which won't work.